# Best practices for using firebase in development and production with react-native-cli

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm new to React Native and Firebase and decided to improve my knowledge in this regard, I read some articles on interaction and how to connect one to the other, but I can't figure out how to split my app in firebase into dev and prod, because for deva, I want to use collections and logging auth ticks of what I use in development, and when compiling in prod I already used a real collection.

I thought that it could be arranged according to the type of prefixes:

- [Prod] My App
- [Dev] My App

But I see that firebase does not allow me to create another app with the same "Android package name" and, accordingly, I need different SHA1 signatures according to debug.keystore and my [release].keystore, what should I do with this? Can you point me in the right direction, what to look at, what to read to understand this issue, because for the most part what I found is 80% water and 20% what I know myself, but it still does not answer my questions how to be with such separation and how it should behave.

Comment: To keep things separate you must use different packages for the DEV and PROD. it is good practice to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 2 Google files, one can also work here.

Example:

Create `Development` and `Staging` folders inside `Android/app/src`  and put your JSON file there

[image]

Add envConfigFiles inside `android/app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [Development: "../../.env.Development",
                              Staging    : "../../.env.Staging",
                              Production : "../../.env.Production"]
```

[image]

Add resValue in defaultConfig `resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.package"`

Add `flavorDimensions`, `signingConfigs`  and `productFlavors` above buildTypes

```
 flavorDimensions "default"
    signingConfigs {
        development {
            storeFile file("../keystore/KeyStore")
            storePassword System.getenv("STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
        staging {
            storeFile file("../keystore/KeyStore")
            storePassword System.getenv("STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
        production {
            storeFile file("../keystore/KeyStore")
            storePassword System.getenv("STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        Development {}
        Staging {}
        Production {}
    }
```

[image]

Add these codes inside `buildTypes`

```
  debug {
            productFlavors.Development.signingConfig signingConfigs.development
            productFlavors.Staging.signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
            productFlavors.Production.signingConfig signingConfigs.production
```

after all of these use the below command to build

```
   "android": "npx nx run-android zype-mobile --mode=StagingDebug",
   "android-prod": "npx nx run-android zype-mobile --mode=ProductionDebug",
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have an open-source project with the work in your answer that I can refer to because currently I don't really understand some of the things you described, for example `file("../keystore/zypeDevKeyStore")` what kind of file is it and where to take it

Comment: Ok give me some time I'll  give you,  this is a Keystore check this blog  https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#:~:text=%7B%20...%20%7D-,signingConfigs,-%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20release%20%7B, 

  and if your app is not live then ignore it for now

Comment: check this for reference https://dev.to/kpiteng/manage-multiple-firebase-projects-in-react-native-2322

Comment: @shivoham Thanks for the resources you pointed out, I read the article from react-native-cli, the article below was quite useful, although I did not understand the working principle of the applicationId, which differed according to the environment, does it not correspond to the namespace in Java classes, and then how can it exist like that?

Comment: don't use the applicationId see my example now